# fancybox different close functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

i would like to have different function when my fancy box is closed using the close button and when my fancy is closed when the transaction is successful.

i used `parent.$.fancybox.close();`
 to close the fancy box when the transaction is successful and i want it to display an alert message. while when the fancy is closed using the closed button i don't want the alert message to prompt. is there a way this could happen?

this is my code for the parent screen:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".popup").fancybox({ 
            'scrolling'         : 'no',
            'autoScale'         : true,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe',
            'closeClick'        : false,
            'autoDimensions'    : true,
            'width'             : 1000,
            'centerOnScroll'    : true,
            'onComplete'        : function() {
                $('#fancybox-frame').load(function() {
                  $('#fancybox-content').height($(this).contents().find('body').height());
                });
              },
            'onClosed'          : function() {alert("Successful!"); }
        });
    });
```

but it still shows the alert message whether it is closed using the close button or successful transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line from your code.

```
'onClosed'          : function() {alert("Successful!"); }
```

and show alert when you call close function explicitly. May be you can create a function like this and call parent.CloseFancyBox() instead of calling parent.$.fancybox.close()

```
function CloseFancyBox()
{
   $.fancybox.close();
   alert("Successful");
}
```